# javascript assigning wrong values to variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, math, random

For some reason this javascript doesn't seem to calculate properly and keeps giving me infinity for some array values.

```
var stock = {
        "data": {
            "portfolio": [
                [1298641715000, 1631.00],
                [1298656616000, 1311.00],
                [1299606578000, 1311.00],
                [1300381305000, 820.50],
                [1300813418000, 2074.80],
                [1300970915000, 3862.50],
                [1300985378000, 4597.35],
                [1301071778000, 3554.85],
                [1301505492000, 5653.05],
                [1302195878000, 4871.80],
                [1302368766000, 4079.80],
                [1306343616000, 5062.60],
                [1307036495000, 5062.60],
                [1307726770000, 7207.60],
                [1307727695000, 6372.60],
                [1312998095000, 5816.10],
                [1313430095000, 5816.10],
                [1316625492000, 7816.10],
                [1316711892000, 6566.10],
                [1316713295000, 7777.10],
                [1316713295000, 8921.60],
                [1316799695000, 10902.10],
                [1316886095000, 8627.10],
                [1318094770000, 7717.10],
                [1318267163000, 6807.10],
                [1326306370000, 8228.30],
                [1327429500000, 9228.30],
                [1328208664000, 10222.05],
                [1329503831000, 10188.65],
                [1330368095000, 11274.15],
                [1330541464000, 12006.75],
                [1330714264000, 13222.25],
                [1331059408000, 14029.75],
                [1331144806000, 15676.55],
                [1333648264000, 17256.02],
                [1334080424000, 18701.62],
                [1336672860000, 19745.42],
                [1336758824000, 20018.77],
                [1336773969000, 21130.77],
                [1337015320000, 20312.47],
                [1337277827000, 21650.02],
                [1339002758000, 22285.97],
                [1341934145000, 23972.67],
                [1341934243000, 24182.67],
                [1342103859000, 25830.67],
                [1342475250000, 25380.67],
                [1342654950000, 25669.09],
                [1343147542000, 25797.43],
                [1343412475000, 25994.43],
                [1343658668000, 26203.43],
                [1343804523000, 26342.43],
                [1343840755000, 26432.43],
                [1343922704000, 25914.43],
                [1343922759000, 26031.43],
                [1345053816000, 26156.43],
                [1345138832000, 26253.43],
                [1345576479000, 26483.43],
                [1345576537000, 26588.43],
                [1345656708000, 26628.43],
                [1346442006000, 26704.43],
                [1346953652000, 26456.43],
                [1347553896000, 26586.43],
                [1347554286000, 26865.43],
                [1347559351000, 27062.43],
                [1347560040000, 27533.43],
                [1347560369000, 27351.43],
                [1347641968000, 26577.43],
                [1348063653000, 26860.43],
                [1348591198000, 26588.43],
                [1348591500000, 26598.43],
                [1348668767000, 26728.43],
                [1348681823000, 27094.43],
                [1349367062000, 27254.43],
                [1349368159000, 27379.43],
                [1350310748000, 27675.43],
                [1350503445000, 27858.43],
                [1350923279000, 27979.43],
                [1352131960000, 27742.43],
                [1353522221000, 27997.43],
                [1353685832000, 28299.43],
                [1355157961000, 28545.43],
                [1355766797000, 28692.43],
                [1355947837000, 28913.43],
                [1357671266000, 29304.43],
                [1357672054000, 29531.44],
                [1358448645000, 28856.44],
                [1358448738000, 29036.44],
                [1358455579000, 29236.44],
                [1358540610000, 29430.44],
                [1360095697000, 30077.44],
                [1360596277000, 30154.44],
                [1360612771000, 30651.44],
                [1360860220000, 30789.44],
                [1360869993000, 31389.44]
            ],
                "portfolio2": [
                [1298641715000, 1631.00],
                [1298656616000, 1311.00],
                [1299606578000, 1311.00],
                [1300381305000, 820.50],
                [1300813418000, 2074.80],
                [1300970915000, 3862.50],
                [1300985378000, 4597.35],
                [1301071778000, 3554.85],
                [1301505492000, 5653.05],
                [1302195878000, 4871.80],
                [1302368766000, 4079.80],
                [1306343616000, 5062.60],
                [1307036495000, 5062.60],
                [1307726770000, 7207.60],
                [1307727695000, 6372.60],
                [1312998095000, 5816.10],
                [1313430095000, 5816.10],
                [1316625492000, 7816.10],
                [1316711892000, 6566.10],
                [1316713295000, 7777.10],
                [1316713295000, 8921.60],
                [1316799695000, 10902.10],
                [1316886095000, 8627.10],
                [1318094770000, 7717.10],
                [1318267163000, 6807.10],
                [1326306370000, 8228.30],
                [1327429500000, 9228.30],
                [1328208664000, 10222.05],
                [1329503831000, 10188.65],
                [1330368095000, 11274.15],
                [1330541464000, 12006.75],
                [1330714264000, 13222.25],
                [1331059408000, 14029.75],
                [1331144806000, 15676.55],
                [1333648264000, 17256.02],
                [1334080424000, 18701.62],
                [1336672860000, 19745.42],
                [1336758824000, 20018.77],
                [1336773969000, 21130.77],
                [1337015320000, 20312.47],
                [1337277827000, 21650.02],
                [1339002758000, 22285.97],
                [1341934145000, 23972.67],
                [1341934243000, 24182.67],
                [1342103859000, 25830.67],
                [1342475250000, 25380.67],
                [1342654950000, 25669.09],
                [1343147542000, 25797.43],
                [1343412475000, 25994.43],
                [1343658668000, 26203.43],
                [1343804523000, 26342.43],
                [1343840755000, 26432.43],
                [1343922704000, 25914.43],
                [1343922759000, 26031.43],
                [1345053816000, 26156.43],
                [1345138832000, 26253.43],
                [1345576479000, 26483.43],
                [1345576537000, 26588.43],
                [1345656708000, 26628.43],
                [1346442006000, 26704.43],
                [1346953652000, 26456.43],
                [1347553896000, 26586.43],
                [1347554286000, 26865.43],
                [1347559351000, 27062.43],
                [1347560040000, 27533.43],
                [1347560369000, 27351.43],
                [1347641968000, 26577.43],
                [1348063653000, 26860.43],
                [1348591198000, 26588.43],
                [1348591500000, 26598.43],
                [1348668767000, 26728.43],
                [1348681823000, 27094.43],
                [1349367062000, 27254.43],
                [1349368159000, 27379.43],
                [1350310748000, 27675.43],
                [1350503445000, 27858.43],
                [1350923279000, 27979.43],
                [1352131960000, 27742.43],
                [1353522221000, 27997.43],
                [1353685832000, 28299.43],
                [1355157961000, 28545.43],
                [1355766797000, 28692.43],
                [1355947837000, 28913.43],
                [1357671266000, 29304.43],
                [1357672054000, 29531.44],
                [1358448645000, 28856.44],
                [1358448738000, 29036.44],
                [1358455579000, 29236.44],
                [1358540610000, 29430.44],
                [1360095697000, 30077.44],
                [1360596277000, 30154.44],
                [1360612771000, 30651.44],
                [1360860220000, 30789.44],
                [1360869993000, 31389.44]
            ],
                "standard": []
        }
    };

    var stockbase = stock.data.portfolio;
    var stock1 = stock.data.portfolio2;

    for (i = 0; i < (stock.data.portfolio2.length); i++) {
        stock.data.portfolio2[i][1] = stock.data.portfolio2[i][1] * Math.random();
    }

    //var performance1 = stock.data.portfolio2;

    var i = 0;

    while(i<stockbase.length)
    {
            if (i == 0){
            stock1[i][0] = stockbase[i][0];
            stock1[i][1] = 0;
        } else if (stockbase[i][1] > stockbase[(i - 1)][1]) {
            stock1[i][0] = stockbase[i][0];
            stock1[i][1] = (stockbase[i][1]) / (stockbase[(i - 1)][1]);
            stock1[i][1] -= 1;
            stock1[i][1] *= 100;
        } else if (stockbase[i][1] < stockbase[(i - 1)][1]) {
            stock1[i][0] = stockbase[i][0];
            stock1[i][1] = ((stockbase[i][1]) / (stockbase[(i-1)][1]));
            stock1[i][1] -= 1;
            stock1[i][1] *= 100;
        } else {
            stock1[i][0] = stockbase[i][0];
            stock1[i][1] = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }

    //console.log(stockbase);
    //console.log(stock1);

    var stockbase = stock.data.portfolio2;
    var stock2 = stock.data.portfolio;

    i = 0;

    while(i<stockbase.length)
    {
            if (i == 0){
            stock2[i][0] = stockbase[i][0];
            stock2[i][1] = 0;
        } else if (stockbase[i][1] > stockbase[(i - 1)][1]) {
            stock2[i][0] = stockbase[i][0];
            stock2[i][1] = (stockbase[i][1]) / (stockbase[(i - 1)][1]);
            stock2[i][1] -= 1;
            stock2[i][1] *= 100;
        } else if (stockbase[i][1] < stockbase[(i - 1)][1]) {
            stock2[i][0] = stockbase[i][0];
            stock2[i][1] = ((stockbase[i][1]) / (stockbase[(i-1)][1]));
            stock2[i][1] -= 1;
            stock2[i][1] *= 100;
        } else {
            stock2[i][0] = stockbase[i][0];
            stock2[i][1] = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }

    console.log(stockbase);
    console.log(stockbase==stock.data.portfolio2);
```

the variable stock 1 works perfectly after the loop without any problems. Interesting part is after the first while loop, stock.data.portfolio2 has the same array values as stock1 does even though no changes are supposed to be made to stock.data.portfolio2.

I'm confused on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your first `for` loop declares `i` as a global variable, not local to the loop as in other languages. Move the `var i = 0` to above the first for loop.

Comment: I just tried that and it set stock1 equal to stock.data.portfolio2 randomized...

Comment: @FactorMystic Actually `i` won't be more global as any variable declared with `var` within this codesnippet. All declarations are hoisted to the beginning of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing the following:

`var stock1 = stock.data.portfolio2;`

you are assigning `stock1` to a reference of the array `stock.data.portfolio2`. That means all changes made to `stock.data.portfolio2` will also be seen in `stock1`. Since `stock.data.portfolio2` is an array of arrays I would recommend creating a function to copy that data for you into your variable `stock1`

```
function copyPortfolio(arr) {
    var s = [];
    for(i = 0; i < (arr.length); i++) { s.push(arr[i].slice()); }
    return s;
}

var stock1 = copyPortfolio(stock.data.portfolio2);
```

Comment: I'm afraid the `slice` trick succeeds only with arrays of literal values, `portfolio2` is a "2D"-array, and it's copied by reference also when using `slice()`.

Comment: ah. you are right :-/ either way it points to his problem. guess I'll have to update my answer with a real solution.